# Using "IN" in importing data from a JSON to postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm importing some data from a JSON file, but I can't use the IN operator in the query, as it generates an error. But it works when I use only 1 condition.

Below is the code:

```
 with dados as (
    select SPLIT_PART (sar_conteudo::text, 'header":', 2)  as conteudo
                from tb_gcc_situacao_arquivo 
                where sar_arquivo = 5012
                --and sar_dt_movimento = '2022-01-12'), --> That's how it works
    and sar_dt_movimento in ('2021-12-30','2021-12-31','2022-01-03')), --> not like this
    dados_2 as (
    select left (conteudo, length(conteudo)-1) as conteudo_2 from dados),
    dados_final as(
    SELECT * 
        from json_to_recordset((select * from dados_2)::json)
    as x
    ("textoLinhaOriginal" text, "descricaoMensagem" text))
    select 
    substring("textoLinhaOriginal",171,18) as captacao, "descricaoMensagem" 
    from dados_final
    where "textoLinhaOriginal" ilike 'RDB  1INCL%'
    and "descricaoMensagem" <> 'EXECUCAO OK'
```

**Searching the internet, I noticed that the json_to_recordset only takes one line. So when passing more than 1 parameter, it will return an error message. How can I resolve this?**

**ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression**

Comment: And what is the error you get?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
     ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Comment: Tryt this : `SELECT json_to_recordset(conteudo_2 ) as x("textoLinhaOriginal" text, "descricaoMensagem" text) from dados_2`